# Why Does a Generic Supertype Declaration Not Permit Referencing to Subtype Objects?

Tags: generics, kotlin, polymorphism, covariance

I'd like to know the background of why a generic supertype parameter does not allow referencing to subtype objects.

```
abstract class Pet()

class Cat: Pet()

interface Retailer<T> {
    fun sell(): T
}

class CatRetailer: Retailer<Cat> {
    override fun sell(): Cat {
        println("Sell Cat")
        return Cat()
    }
}

// Type MismatchError prior to compilation  
val steveIrwinTheAnimalEnslaver: Retailer<Pet> = CatRetailer()
```

The variable definition results in a type mismatch error where the compiler expects a type of `Retailer<Pet>`.

However, `Pet` is a supertype of `Cat`. Why doesn't polymorphism work like below?

```
open class SuperClassName() {}

class SubClassName : SuperClassName()

var variableName: SuperClassName = SubClassName()
```

Comment: Read about variance in https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance

Comment: So I read the article, but I didn't understand because the article assumes that the reader has background knowledge in Java.

Comment: Ok, since nobody added a duplicate yet, I showed how it works in your case and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pet` is a supertype of `Cat`, but `Retailer<Pet>` is *not* a supertype of `Retailer<Cat>`. To see why imagine you added a method:

```
abstract class Pet()

class Cat: Pet()
class Dog: Pet()

interface Retailer<T> {
    fun sell(): T
    fun buy(x: T): Unit
}

// only really knows how to buy cats
val steveIrwinTheAnimalEnslaver: Retailer<Pet> = CatRetailer() 

// legal for any Retailer<Pet>
steveIrwinTheAnimalEnslaver.buy(Dog())
```

In this case your options are:

1. Use `Retailer<out Pet>`, which disallows calling members like `buy` which "consume" `T`. You can think of it as `Retailer<any subtype of Pet>`, and you won't be much wrong. There is also the dual `Retailer<in Pet>` which allows calling `buy` but not `sell`.
2. Declare `interface Retailer<out T>` which disallows *declaring* `buy` and means "if `A` is a subtype of `B`, then `Retailer<A>` is a subtype of `Retailer<B>`.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote: 
`class CatRetailer: Retailer<Cat>`
In order to makethe code to work you need to write :
`class CatRetailer: Retailer<Pet>`

Cat retailer doesn't implement an interface of pet, it implements an interface of cat. If it would implement interface of pet, you could write :

`val steveIrwinTheAnimalEnslaver: Retailer<Pet>`

when implementing an interface of **cat** you are saying that your retailer is  of type **cat** and cat only.

Interface of type Cat **doesn't** extend/implement interface of type Pet.

This is isn't the the case of the example you gave with the subclassing.

To summarise: `Interface<B>` is not an `interface<A>` even if B extends A.
But B is A.

I hope was clear enough.